# MongoDB full text search, autocomplete on two fields

Tags: mongodb-atlas-search

I am trying to implement [MongoDB atlas search](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/), and the objective is autocomplete on 2 fields.

I currently have this implementation:

```js
const searchStep = {
    $search: {
        // Read more about compound here:
        // https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/compound/
        compound: {
            must: [
                {
                    autocomplete: {
                        query,
                        path: 'name',
                    },
                },
                {
                    autocomplete: {
                        query,
                        path: 'description',
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
}
```

This does not seem to work, seems to only work when there is **both** a match on the name **AND** description. How can I fix this, so I query for *both* name and description?

I now tried using the **wildcard** option:

```js
{
    wildcard: {
        query,
        path: ['name', 'description'],
        allowAnalyzedField: true,
    }
}
```

But the wildcard solution does not seem to work - no relevant results are returned...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are trying to match on `name` or `subscription`, use `should:` instead of `must:`

`must` will require that all of the subqueries match, where as `should` requires that only 1 of them does.

```
const searchStep = {
    $search: {
        // Read more about compound here:
        // https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/compound/
        compound: {
            should: [
                {
                    autocomplete: {
                        query,
                        path: 'name',
                    },
                },
                {
                    autocomplete: {
                        query,
                        path: 'description',
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
}
```