# MongoDB full text search, autocomplete on multiple fields to search a number

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I have a data collection like
`{ type: "customer", customer: {  name: "Adam",  mobile_number: "+919988776655"  } }` ,
and i am trying to use this query like reference from previously asked question here: [MongoDB full text search, autocomplete on two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63186283/mongodb-full-text-search-autocomplete-on-two-fields)
I updated my query to this:

```
const searchStep = {
    $search: {
        // Read more about compound here:
        // https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/compound/
        compound: {
            should: [
                {
                    autocomplete: {
                        "query": "9988776655",
                        path: "customer.mobile_number",
                    },
                },
                {
                    autocomplete: {
                        "query": "9988776655",
                        path: "customer.name",
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
}
```

But it does not return any result. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

```
const searchStep = {
    $search: {
        // Read more about compound here:
        // https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/compound/
        compound: {
            should: [
                {
                    autocomplete: {
                        "query": "9988776655",
                        path: "customer.mobile_number",
                    },
                },
                {
                    autocomplete: {
                        "query": "9988776655",
                        path: "customer.name",
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
}
```

This is what i tried, and i was expecting to get the result the object containing mobile_number "9988776655"